# PS3 dualshock 3 fails to connect to Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: bluetooth, controller, ubuntu-22.04

I've been trying to connect a dualshock 3 controller to my Ubuntu 22.04, and despite how easy it looks on tuto and websites like those :

[doc-ubuntu](https://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/dualshock)

[tuto youtube](https://youtu.be/i3oZfa6LAMo)

in my case it's not at all. When connecting the controller to my machine and waiting in the bluetooth settings I do have a window asking if I want to authorize the bluetooth connexion :

[authorize bluetooth connection ?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vX4hK.png)

And when I do, I have a profile connexion for it in my bluetooth settings, but not connected :

[controller's profile in bluetooth settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWoLl.png)

But it won't connect when I click the connect button, it just try and come back to the state of the previous image above.

What I've tried :

1. Is my bluetooth driver the problem ? Doesn't seems like it :

```
$ hciconfig -a
hci0:   Type: Primary  Bus: USB
    BD Address: FC:77:74:7F:90:7B  ACL MTU: 1021:4  SCO MTU: 96:6
    UP RUNNING PSCAN ISCAN INQUIRY 
    RX bytes:744946 acl:0 sco:0 events:25044 errors:0
    TX bytes:632998 acl:0 sco:0 commands:9119 errors:0
    Features: 0xff 0xfe 0x0f 0xfe 0xdb 0xff 0x7b 0x87
    Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3 
    Link policy: RSWITCH HOLD SNIFF 
    Link mode: PERIPHERAL ACCEPT 
    Name: 'PL290-PRO'
    Class: 0x7c010c
    Service Classes: Rendering, Capturing, Object Transfer, Audio, Telephony
    Device Class: Computer, Laptop
    HCI Version: 4.2 (0x8)  Revision: 0x100
    LMP Version: 4.2 (0x8)  Subversion: 0x100
    Manufacturer: Intel Corp. (2)
```

Version 4.2 should work just fine according to ubuntu-doc..

2. Is it something else with my Ubuntu ? Don't think so...
3. I can connect my controller via usb with xboxdrv as suggested on the ubuntu-doc page and it works, but I want it to be in bluetooth.

Here it is, I think that's all
Pls help, thks

Comment: This question is probably off topic for Stackoverflow and might be better suited on https://unix.stackexchange.com/. I have found the following instructions helpful when having problems connecting DualShock controllers on Linux https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Sony_DualShock#Bluetooth

Comment: @ukBaz I've actually posted it on https://askubuntu.com/questions/1470520/ps3-dualshock-3-fails-to-connect-to-ubuntu-22-04 but got no real answer that could help... But the link you send seems very promising, I'll look into it tonight back from work. You can put the same answer on askubuntu and I'll delete this post once done

Comment: @ukBaz and no it did not worked... Followed the procedure without any error and still not working... I start to wonder if the Bluetooth of my controller is not dead.. how could I test that ?

Answer (score 1):

Found the work-around.

I ran into the same issue.  I loved how native support for PS3 controllers was added, but I was discouraged when it broke.

However, this is actually intended, according to the bug report.  Due to security concerns, this functionality was taken out for now and will be fixed in a later release, but there is a work-around for now:

From https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bluez/+bug/2045931

- Edit `/etc/bluetooth/input.conf`

- Uncomment `ClassicBondedOnly=true` and change to `ClassicBondedOnly=false`
- Restart bluetooth: `systemctl restart bluetooth`

This should reverse the security "fix" and allow your controllers to connect again.  No failed pin requests anymore.